# What will pole reversal cause to modern world and civilization?

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, geophysics, geomagnetism

I don't think it's just a matter of reorienting maps and recalibrating compasses.
In any case, how long does a inversion last? hours, days, weeks, years? If it lasts days or more.... would  Sun fry Earth surface?

Comment: A side note, the wiki has some great info about geomagnetic reversals in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal

Comment: this question would be appropriate for https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Our knowledge of reversals comes from numerical models and paleomagnetic records in rocks, and the latter provide pretty sketchy information because a reversal is a blink of an eye in geologic time. However, as the [Wikipedia article states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal#Duration), most paleomagnetists estimate that reversals take about 1,000 to 10,000 years. The risk from radiation comes from a likely weakening of the magnetic field, but [the field will not disappear completely](https://www.nasa.gov/topics/earth/features/2012-poleReversal.html), so the risk is not very large. There's no evidence that any species have ever gone extinct because of a reversal. The reduced field and increased flux of charged particles could ["result in increased risks for satellites, aviation and ground-based electrical infrastructure"](https://www.livescience.com/61603-what-if-magnetic-pole-reversal.html), but we'd have hundreds of years to adapt the technology. And there might be aurorae at lower latitudes, which would be pretty cool!

Comment: Aurorae at lower latitudes and cancer at younger age.

Comment: "There's no evidence that any species have ever gone extinct because of a reversal." Ours is the only species which uses electricity! Our civilization completely depends on electricity.

Comment: We have used electricity widely for a little over a century.  Ten centuries from now, who knows what we will depend on?